# Identifying Unused CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, css, optimization

I was currently working on a freelance project to Upgrade their current website and they want some   specific features from the old site copied over. but Unfortunately, the old site's CSS and JS are both in single, massive files ("style.css" and "script.js"). So I need a way to efficiently identify which CSS/JS rules are actually used on the various pages and which can be safely removed.

I tried manually searching through the code but couldn't catch all use cases.

Comment: What have you tried? See [ask] please

Comment: Maybe have a read here: https://edgemesh.com/blog/remove-unused-javascript and here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/unused-css-rules ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [PurifyCSS](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss) to identify and remove unused CSS and [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) to remove unused JS functions and variables.